# Angularjs configure md-tabs arrow (color, visibility)

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I am using angularjs material tabs https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs .

Firstly, how to set the color for the left and right arrows?

```
<md-toolbar >
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools tb">
        <md-tabs class="tab">
            <md-tab ng-repeat = "item in toDoList track by $index" label="{{item.name}}" >
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

For example, set the color of the arrows from white to other colors(like red) in the image and fiddle below[image: set tab color]

[jsfiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ayhr5or8/)

Next, how to make the arrows always visible? In the image and jsfiddle below, if there is no tab overflow, the left and right arrows will not appear.[image: set arrow visibility]

[jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ym1uvt46/)

Lastly, is there any formal/specific name for the left and right arrows, like pagination arrow? Because I can't find much related topic about the md-tabs arrow, maybe I used the incorrect keyword for the arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For arrows color you can use this rule :

```
md-toolbar:not(.md-menu-toolbar) md-icon{
  fill:red;
}
```

[jsfiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ayhr5or8/1/)

But to make them always visible, I don't think it's possible unless you modify the Angular Material source code